# Frigidaire Water Pressure Setting

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Frigidaire Gallery Series refrigerator that was having issues making ice. I had a technician come out and he was able to adjust the water pressure setting on the refrigerator from the control panel on the outside of the refrigerator. We had to unplug the refrigerator and it reset itself. Anyone know how to get to this setting?

Comment: I have never  seen a pressure adjustment from control panel. Can you provide picture

Comment: What exact model number? The Gallery series is not specific enough for anyone to look up model-specific instructions.